# Accessing an Angular Service from within a function, inside a class, inside a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-service

```
module Helper {

    export class ListController {
        static batchDelete(data) {
            // Do something with Angular's $http ...
            $http.post(data)
        }
    }
}

// On click function
Helper.ListController.batchDelete(toBeDeleted);
```

Deleting data from the array works fine, however, I would like to do an $http request from within that function. How do I access Angular's $http service inside `batchDelete()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample:

```
 // Do something with Angular's $http ...
 $http.post(data)
```

You need to get `$http` injected. The ideal way to do this would be to create a class as a service and then let angular inject the service into your controller.

## More

I have a video on the subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM